# Pandas to_sql int column turning to float64 because of null values

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am running python 3.10, pandas 1.5.2, sqlalchemy 1.4.46, and pyodbc 4.0.35 on an Ubuntu subsystem on Windows (WSL2).

I think the issue I am having was a bug in prior pandas versions, but everyone is saying it has been fixed, so I am not sure why I am having this issue.

I have a dataframe like this: df=

| int_col_1 | int_col_2 | string_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 'val1' |
| 2 | 20 | None |
| 3 | None | 'val3' |

Then I push this to an MSSQL database using this code:

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password + ';Encrypt=no'
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Or with dtypes like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String
df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={'int_col1_1':Integer(), 'int_col_2':Integer(), 'string_col':String()})
```

Either way this is what is returned if I pull the table from SQL:

| int_col_1 | int_col_2 | string_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.0 | 'val1' |
| 2 | 20.0 | None |
| 3 | NaN | 'val3' |

You'll notice that int_col_1 is fine (`int64`), string_col is fine (object with `NoneType`), but int_col_2 is turned into `float64`.

I know there are methods to correct the data after pulling from SQL, but I am looking for a way to get the data to be correct in SQL when pushed from pandas and I have no idea how to do that. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the column to an `Int64` dtype

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, np.nan]})
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('Int64')
df
```

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   <NA>
```

Comment: Documentation on `Int64` dtype: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can do this after pulling the data, but I was hoping there was a way to get the data in the database as the correct type.

Comment: After getting access to view the actual database, I was able to confirm that the issue was not in there and in fact only once it became a dataframe again which means changing the data type after is the only solution. Therefore, I marked this as correct. Thanks for the help/